# Hessian determinant equals 0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant, hessian-matrix

The question is to find all the critical points of the function, then determine whether each point is either a minimum, maximum or saddle point.

The function is: $f(x,y) = x^3 - x^2 - x + y^3 - 2y^2$

I found that the critical points are:

$$P_1 = (1, 0),\quad P_2 = (-1/3, 0),\quad P_3 = (1, 4/3),\quad P_4 = (-1/3, 4/3)$$

I found the hessian matrix to be (for any $P$):
$$H = \begin{pmatrix}6x-2  & 0\\ 0 & -4+6y \end{pmatrix} $$

The problem is when I want to determine for $P_1$ and $P_2$, since their determinants equal to $0$.

I don't know how to solve for these two cases.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format.

Comment: What would you do if the second derivative of a single-variable function was equal to zero at a critical point?

Comment: The hessian determinant is $16$ and $-16$ at these points.